# HttpListener "This site can’t be reached"

Tags: c#, httplistener

I use OAuth in my app and launch an external browser to let the user log in, then catch the returnUri to localhost with an HttpListener.

Thing is, this listener renders the webpage correctly most of the time, but sometimes it shows "This site can’t be reached" exception in chrome.

```
This site can’t be reachedlocalhost refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

It does not throw an exception when this happens.

I do get the context from http.GetContext() so the listener does catch the browser request on localhost, but for some reason the browser sometimes shows the error message instead of rendering the "login succes.html" page.

When it gives that error it tends to keep doing that, although it does return to working again after a few calls. so it's quite inconsistent.

I've tried a lot of things like:

- Running it on the UI thread (so no background task)
- shutting the listener down and creating a new one, now I have a
  static listener that I start and stop although that doesn't seem to
  matter much.
- Thread.Sleep(100) to see if it might be a deadlock or
  something.

It won't budge, does anyone here have any clue what could be causing this?

Here are the relevant bits:
I have a modal form that with a static HttpListener:

```
static HttpListener http = new HttpListener();
```

The form then kicks off the login code on a background thread (to keep the UI responsive):

```
Task.Run(SignInOIDC);

        private void SignInOIDC() {
     try {

         if (!http.Prefixes.Contains(OidcOptions.RedirectUri)) http.Prefixes.Add(OidcOptions.RedirectUri);
         http.Start();

         // todo use the logout url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302863/logging-out-from-identityserver-quietly
         _client = new OidcClient(OidcOptions);
         _loginState = _client.PrepareLoginAsync().Result;

        

         // open system browser to start authentication
         var uri = _loginState.StartUrl;
         var proc = Process.Start(_loginState.StartUrl);

         // wait for the authorization response.
         var context = http.GetContext(); // blocking call, it does return from this so it catches the request         
         WriteLoginSucceeded(context);               
         var formData = context.Request.Url.ToString();
         ShutdownHttp();
         this.Activate();   
          
         // read token
         OIDCLoginResult = _client.ProcessResponseAsync(formData, _loginState).Result;
       
         if (_cancelled) return;
         this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
             DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; // this closes the form
         });
     }
     catch (Exception ex) {               
         var msg = Util.ReadException(ex);
         MessageBox.Show(msg);               
     }
     finally {
         ShutdownHttp();
     }
 }


        private string _hmtl;
        private string HTML { get {
                if (_hmtl == null) {
                    var fld = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
                    var path = Path.Combine(fld, "LoginSuccess.html");
                    _hmtl = File.ReadAllText(path);
                }
                return _hmtl;
            } }

        private void WriteLoginSucceeded(HttpListenerContext context) {            
            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML);
            response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
            Stream output = response.OutputStream;
            output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            output.Close();
        }
 private void ShutdownHttp() {
     try {
         if (http != null) {
             if (http.IsListening) http.Stop();                  
         }
     }
     catch { }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you  using the blocking call `GetContext`  instead of [begingetcontext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener.begingetcontext?view=net-7.0) ,is this by design?

Comment: Had GetContextAsync at first, switched to GetContext as one of the attempts to get it stable. I'm already on a background thread so not too worried about blokcing.  Thought it might be a threading issue. Thing is, that does not seem to be the issue as the call does return.

Comment: You need to dispose the `response` and `output` with `using`. Otherwise the response doesn't get fully sent before you shutdown the socket.

Comment: @Charlieface tried a lot of different ways of wrapping the response and stream in using, flushing stream, closing both, but that did not fix it. Guess I'll stick with the Sleep(150) it also gives the user a chance to briefly see the succes page before the app activates itself again.

Answer (score 0):

Think I fixed it by adding a pause, haven't seen it in a while.

```
  private void WriteLoginSucceeded(HttpListenerContext context) {            
      HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
      byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HTML);
      response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;
      Stream output = response.OutputStream;
      output.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
      output.Flush();
      output.Close();
      Thread.Sleep(150);
  }
```

It seems the forms would close very quickly afterwards, that calls the ShutDownHttp method. This 150ms pause seems to give it enough time to get the page out the door.